# Detecting Assignment

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to detect assignment in a script (=), when it should be equality (==). I have the following in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^=]=[^=]");
```

This returns true:

```
p.matcher("a=b").matches();
```

This returns false:

```
p.matcher("a = b").matches();
```

I'm stumped as to what is happening here, can anyone tell me why the second expression doesn't match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^=]` will only match one character that is not an `=`, you probably want to match one or more, like this:

```
[^=]+=[^=]+
```

The `+` after the character class means repeat the previous element one or more times.

Answer (score 3):

`[^=]` matches exactly one character in the class. You want `"[^=]+=[^=]+"`.

edit in response to comment: If you just want to skip whitespace, you could have something like `"[^\s=]+\s*=\s*[^\s=]+"`

Comment: Wouldn't something like that be matched though: "a b = c d" which is probably unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

[Matcher.matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) only tests against the entire input string.

You want [Matcher.find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29), which will locate a partial match.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" here is that Java is matching against the complete string, it is as if in other languages the Start and End anchors are given (`^[^=]=[^=]$`).

You have to know that and adjust the pattern accordingly.

`"[^=]=[^=]"` matches 3 characters.

1. "a=b" ==> obvious
2. "a = b" the `a` is matched from the `[^=]` then the pattern requires a `=` ==> the pattern fails.